# Why isn't bin/console script found nor recreated in "bin" after composer install?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-4.3, symfony-flex

I changed my composer.json and suddenly, when I do

```
rm -rf vendor/* && rm -rf bin/* && composer update
```

I get error messages at the end of the process, because the Symfony `console` isn't found in the folder `bin`. When I manually copy it there from another project it works, but that cannot be the solution.

The error message is as follows:

```
 ....
  - Installing symfony/test-pack (v1.0.6): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/web-server-bundle (v4.3.6): Loading from cache
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions: Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  Could not open input file: ./bin/console
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-update-cmd
```

The error is clear, since the bin folder does contain symlinks to loads of other scripts, but not the console script itself.

I tried clearing the composer cache, but it makes no difference.

If I create a complete new empty folder and copy the `composer.json` file there and run `composer install`, everything is fine and the `console` script is in the `bin` folder, where it should be.

What is the difference?

When I run it later automatically for automatic deployment, how can I be sure, that the console will be there?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not delete your `bin/console` script. That's part of your application, it's equivalent to `public/index.php` but as a console entry point.

Most likely, that file should be kept in your source code repository.

So the best way to guarantee that file will be there when you deploy would be: do not delete it, it's part of your source code and should be kept.

---

The file is created during `install` on an empty folder because the flex recipe gets executed during `install` because of two things:

- Flex recipes are only executed during install, not during update.
- [The flex recipe for symfony/console](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/console/3.3/manifest.json) will copy the whole `bin` directory to create it anew, but it won't overwrite an existing directory. (Hence, if you keep this directory and its contents on your repo, as you should, it won't be overwritten when you deploy your project on production).